# wsimport out of memory issues in Java 1.6

Tags: java, wsimport

I'm using wsimport in Java 1.6 (i.e. build 1.6.0-b105) on Windows XP 5.1 and I'm getting a out of memory exception. I used to JConsole and it seems wsimport process is maxing out at 64 MB. How can I increase the heap memory for wsimport?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me setting environment variable WSIMPORT_OPTS (suggested in another answer, and apparently working in older versions of wsimport) does not seem to have any effect.

For me the following *does* work: instead of `wsimport` use

> `java -classpath $JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport`

where `$JAVA_HOME` is the JDK (not JRE) root folder.

On this Java command line you can then add whatever JVM options you want.  (I needed `-Djavax.net.debug=all` for SSL trust debugging.)

(I'm using Ubuntu with OpenJDK 6, package version 6b20-1.9.7-0ubuntu1.)

Answer (score 1):

wsimport accepts JVM arguments through the WSIMPORT_OPTS environment variable. So on Windows, try running "set WSIMPORT_OPTS=-Xmx512M" on the command-line before running wsimport to give the JVM 512Mb of heap.

Comment: Setting the argument as WSIMPORT_OPTS=-Xmx512M doesn't help. The memory through JConsole is still 64MB and I'm still getting the out of memory error.

Comment: Strange, you're in the same console session right (ie running the SET command in the same window as the wsimport command)? Try checking you're wsimport.bat file and adding the -Xmx flag directly after %JAVA% in the ":LAUNCH" section. ("%JAVA% -Xmx512M %WSIMPORT_OPTS% -jar "%JAXWS_HOME%\lib\jaxws-tools.jar" %*")

Comment: With Java 1.6 JAX WS comes bundled in rt.jar and wsimport comes as an executable like javac or java. There is no wsimport.bat however, creating one and calling wsimport with -Xmx setting doesn't work. Not sure how one can pass memory options to wsimport.exe

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a sufficiently modern JDK, you can use the `-Xnocompile` option and then supply the `javac` process with additional memory the usual way.  (Try `wsimport --help` to see if your version supports the flag.)

Answer (score 1):

wsimport seems to be able to pass through java arguments using the -J option:

```
wsimport -J-Xmx1024M ...
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured to get past this issue. The easiest way is to use Netbeans (I'm using v6.8). Replace the default memory settings in Netbeans.conf under /etc directory like this: -J-Xms768m -J-Xmx768m -J-XX:PermSize=128m and follow the usual way to create Web Service Client following JAX WS in Netbeans. From JConsole, I see that loading ~18,500 classes overall in the memory tends to use between ~400MB to ~650MB. The # of classes generated based on my WSDL/Schemas are ~1500 classes. Hope this helps for someone running into a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just do as below(WINDOWS)

```
set CLASSPATH=<JAVA_HOME>\lib\tools.jar;%classpath%
java -Xmx1024m com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport <YOUR_WSDL>
```

It should work